# For a floating floor - Is it safe to use an underlayment above an existing vapor barrier?

Tags: vinyl-flooring, vapor-barrier, underlayment

I have a concrete slab floor, and it was very uneven, so I placed a vapor barrier down (6ml poly) and then I nailed 3/4" plywood overtop. This fixed a lot of issues with the floor being uneven.

Now I want to install a floating floor. I would like to use an underlayment that is waterproof because I will be installing it in the bathroom, however, all underlayments state that they are a vapor barrier. Therefore, my plywood would be directly between two vapor barriers. Is this an issue?

It would be something like:

1. concrete
2. 6mil poly vapor barrier
3. 3/4" plywood
4. underlayment (vapor barrier)
5. vinyl floating floor

I'm worried that the plywood could get moisture trapped in it and rot

Comment: Why have you labeled the underlayment a vapor barrier? What is the underlayment and how is it secured? Who says all underlayments are vapor barriers?

Comment: You generally don't need/want two vapor barriers.

Comment: @SteveSh How about typical walls: moisture barrier on outside of wall and vapor barrier on inside of wall.

Comment: Doesn't the typical moisture barrier/house wrap (I assume this is what you're talking about) breath a bit, so is really not a vapor barrier, but rather a vapor retardent?

Comment: @SteveSh Hmmm…I think you’re right for some moisture barriers, but not for all moisture barriers… I think. Maybe it’s the air volume (air space in wall could be 4-6” thick) and a sheet of plywood would be much less and filled solid with material. (It’s also a vertical space which would allow any trapped moisture to migrate vertically.) I don’t get it.